# How to provide efficient collision detection and response for spherical objects and triangular terrain?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, computational-geometry, glm-math

I've been trying to make efficient collision detection between objects and terrain. The objects are represented by mobile spheres and the terrain is made of static triangles.
**So far, I managed to implement a collision algorithm, but it has some major issues:**
1. It's very resource-consuming.
2. Collision only works on one side of the triangles.
3. Multiple, simultaneous collisions give bad results.
**Below I've put the algorithm that I have. It's based on an article from [realtimecollisiondetection.net](http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/blog/?p=103), and it's using the GLM math library. I've simplified loops, variable names, unnecessary code and class members:**

```
//Class definitions:  
class Sphere
{
     public:
     float x;
     float y;
     float z;
     float radius;
     float sqradius;
     float xmov;
     float ymov;
     float zmov;
};
class TriangularWall
{
     public:
     float x[3];
     float y[3];
     float z[3];
     glm::vec3 Normal;
};
```

```
using namespace glm; 
Sphere Obj;
TriangularWall Wall;
//Assume that the 2 objects above are constructed. I didn't include their constructors because they looked ugly. 
float rr=Obj.sqradius;  
vec3 A=vec3(Wall.x[0], Wall.y[0], Wall.z[0])-vec3(Obj.x, Obj.y, Obj.z);  
vec3 B=vec3(Wall.x[1], Wall.y[1], Wall.z[1])-vec3(Obj.x, Obj.y, Obj.z);
vec3 C=vec3(Wall.x[2], Wall.y[2], Wall.z[2])-vec3(Obj.x, Obj.y, Obj.z);  
vec3 V=cross(B-A, C-A);  
float d=dot(A, V);  
float e=dot(V, V);  
float di=d;  
float ei=e;
vec3 Ai;
vec3 Bi;
vec3 Ci;
vec3 Vi;
if(!(di*di>rr*ei))
{
      float aa=dot(A, A);
      float ab=dot(A, B);
      float ac=dot(A, C);
      float bb=dot(B, B);
      float bc=dot(B, C);
      float cc=dot(C, C);
      if(!(aa>rr && ab>aa && ac>aa))
      if(!(bb>rr && ab>bb && bc>bb))
      if(!(cc>rr && ac>cc && bc>cc))
      {
            vec3 AB=B-A;
            vec3 BC=C-B;
            vec3 CA=A-C;
            float d1=ab-aa;
            float d2=bc-bb;
            float d3=ac-cc;
            float e1=dot(AB, AB);
            float e2=dot(BC, BC);
            float e3=dot(CA, CA);
            vec3 Q1=A*e1-d1*AB;
            vec3 Q2=B*e2-d2*BC;
            vec3 Q3=C*e3-d3*CA;
            vec3 QC=C*e1-Q1;
            vec3 QA=A*e2-Q2;
            vec3 QB=B*e3-Q3;
            if(!(dot(Q1, Q1)>rr*e1*e1 && dot(Q1, QC)>0)
            if(!(dot(Q2, Q2)>rr*e2*e2 && dot(Q2, QA)>0)
            if(!(dot(Q3, Q3)>rr*e3*e3 && dot(Q3, QB)>0)
            {
                  vec3 ObjectMov=vec3(Obj.xmov, Obj.ymov, Obj.zmov);
                  if(dot(ObjectMov, Wall.Normal)<0)
                  ObjectMov-=dot(ObjectMov, Wall.Normal);
                  Obj.xmov=ObjectMov [0];
                  Obj.ymov=ObjectMov [1];
                  Obj.zmov=ObjectMov [2];
            }
      }
}
```

For the third issue, I re-made the above algorithm (simply stopping the object on the corresponding axis if a collision still takes place). However, this loads up the program significantly, and doesn't produce that nice effects.
I'm also aware that I could include a few performance tweaks to the algorithm above, but I don't see anything that could improve performance by a significant margin.
*I know that I could also use octrees, however they seemed pretty complicated to me and I'm also worried that they could, in some situations, create a lot of latency.*
**Therefore, is there any way to improve the algorithm I used in order to fix its main issues? Or should I just try to use another one?**

Comment: When you said "triangular terrain" at first I thought you just meant you had a height map and were managing the polygons as triangles. Is that essentially what your "TriangularWalls" amounts to? If they are equivalent, I'd think you would get better performance by keeping track of it as a grid of height values. Also this would allow you to make certain assumptions about where you expect the sphere to be relative to the terrain.

Comment: No, TriangularWalls simply defines a triangle with a normal, which is then used in the algorithm. I didn't implement a height map yet, but it sounds like a good idea. @Loduwijk

Comment: Like this pseudocode `y0 = (int)(sphere.y - sphere.radius); y1 = (int)(sphere.y + sphere.radius)+1; same thing for x0/x1/z0/z1; for(y = y0 to y1) for(x = x0 to x1) if(z0 <= height_map[x][y]) then there might be a collision so do your more detailed check else no possible collision`

Comment: That would not be an accurate check. That would just be a rough initial check to see if you should bother to check closer. That's something that is sometimes done in collision detection, though you might already be aware of that.

Comment: @Loduwijk Yes. I already have a broader phase that I didn't include in the example code, because it looked ugly. Basically, the entire space is divided into 30×30×30 cells which store the ID of each terrain piece and object, and only objects / terrain from the same or adjacent cells are put into the closer collision phase. However, it's still pretty laggy. And it eats up quite a lot of memory, so I'll try implementing height maps instead.

Comment: If a standard video-game-style heightmap is sufficient then I'd recommend it, but before you go doing an overhaul just make sure you decide if it is sufficient. They are not as flexible as freeform polygons. Every x/y point is necessarily an integer on a square grid... (1,1), (1,2),... (1,n), (2,1), (2,2),... (2,n),... (n,n). Limited concave shapes, no holes, no completely vertical walls, and x/y coordinates snapped to the nearest integer. If you want to overcome any of those limitations with heightmaps you need to implement heightmap plus something else to go with it. But its fast/easy.

Comment: What do you call a collision ? Do you mean checking that the sphere intersects no triangle, or do you mean finding the remaining distance before the first intersection with a triangle occurs ? These are two different problems.

Comment: @Yves Daoust I mean checking whether it intersects a triangle.

Comment: What do you mean by "Multiple, simultaneous collisions give bad results" ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust If the object is sliding downhill on a slope and reaches a vertical wall, it goes through it. I had to implement something which stops the object in place if it'd still run into the wall after the initial collision test, which significantly increases latency and provides ugly effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that what you call "resource consuming" is too high running-time, the number of triangles must be significant. So the first thing to do is to reduce the number of triangles to be tested against.

You mentioned oct-trees. More generally, a hierarchy of bounding volumes is the way to go. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume_hierarchy.) Speedups will be tremendous for million triangles. In your particular case, I would probably opt for a binary tree of bounding spheres.

---

Note that before implementing this, you will already obtain a speedup by precomputing the bounding sphere of every triangle (the center of the sphere is the center of the circumscribed circle, i.e. the intersection of the mediator planes and the plane of the triangle). Then non-intersecting triangles are detected by comparing the distance between the centers to the sum of radii.

---

Regarding the exact intersection test between the sphere and a triangle, I am afraid that there is no free lunch. Using the "inflating/deflating" method, the center of the sphere can be inside either the right prism over the triangle, one of three truncated cylindres around the edges or one of three spheres around the vertices.

Whatever approach you take, you will have to deal with that complexity of the case analysis.

Comment: I have partly implemented the bounding spheres for the triangles. But instead I'd check if the squared distance is smaller than the squared sum of the radii in order to avoid square rooting.

Comment: @John: goes without saying. But micro-optimizations come after the choice of efficient algorithms.

Comment: Turned out that the main lag source was from rendering the objects' models. I ran a benchmark with 20004 objects without rendering them and 10000 triangles and it had a frame time of about 65 ms. With 200 rendered objects and 10000 triangles it was at about 350 ms. I should look into the shaders instead (and maybe use a lower poly model...)